# Editing posts - feature request

Tags: feature-request

I had a suggested edit to one of my posts here:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158765

The editor involved already knew that, because of my baby-level knowledge of syntax, I believe that the phrase *One of the main problems* is the Subject in the sentence in the question:

- One of the main problems was people doing X.

Because they disagreed with me about this, they decided to rewrite my post so that it reflected their own interesting idea of the grammar.

What can we do about edits that flagrantly ignore the author's intent? Can we have a wall of shame, please? Or a ducking stool or something?

---

**Note**: If you fancy a giggle, read the edit summary given by the editor!

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think if someone has enough edit suggestions rejected then they might be restricted from editing in the future?

Comment: Or, if necessary, moderators can restrict a user from suggesting edits. That action will only happen for a sustained run of rejections, though.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for the response. I must admit I'd prefer a ducking stool though ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that was just an absent-minded slip (Ricky already had a chat with me). I've accidentally approved something before and then had to go and roll back the edit myself :/

Comment: As they say in Italian "Mah?" I don't know, that was such a huge change to the original it's difficult to make such a mistake. A change in tense, a spelling correction which is actually incorrect etc. those edits can slip through the net but that one? All I know is that good edits which should be approved sometimes aren't, and trivial edits are nearly always approved. And I myself have approved of trivial edits because at least they didn't do any harm.

Comment: That  edit I mentioned previously? It was approved, the *full stop* was moved before the end of the speech marks. Words fail me. If Ricky realized his mistake, then that's fine.

Comment: Dude, that is so uncool...to take your answer and rewrite it and then add their own 200 words.  It's almost criminal.  No wait, it is.  Was this edit accepted?

Comment: @michael The edit is shown in the link in the post above. Green on the right-hand side is new; red on the left-hand side is deleted.

Comment: @michael_timofeev yes, that's correct.

Comment: We have to figure out some ways to (1) increase the rep points that allow editing and reviewing, (2) penalize those who edit that way, i.e. a warning with ban to edit for a certain period of time, (3) limit the number of words that could be edited for low-rep users, (4) permanently ban those who keep making bad edits for a certain number of times (they can live without editing anything), (5) limit the number of edits a low-rep user can do like limiting the close-vote, (6) prohibit a low-rep user (under 5K for example) from editing high-rep users's post (over 10K), etc.

Comment: I saw only **one-reputation** user editing [a post](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/38205/revisions) a few days ago and is it really allowed? I don't think it is the right way to allow such a low rep user to edit any post. I didn't reject the edit because I wanted to keep it as a record for an edit and approval by one user in this community. One user approved that edit. That seems to be a problem.

Comment: @Rathony anyone, anonymous, unregistered, a stray cat can suggest edits that's why we have the queue, just to make sure that nobody abuses the system. Think if the user who suggested that (vengeful?) edit on Araucaria's post had enough rep not to have his edit reviewed. Think if it had been on a post that was two years old written by someone who was no longer active on the site.  It just shows you that it's not just low-rep users who take advantage of the system.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's why I suggested prohibiting low-rep users (under 5K) from editing high-rep user's post (over 10K). I think it is an ideal solution. Again, many edits are done by those who don't know what editing is all about. Especially one-rep user (I think it should be those under 1K or 2K) should not touch anything. They have to learn how it works here first before editing anything.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what the guy did to the post was wrong...I think there needs to be some changes to the system to prevent this sort of activity...maybe two reviews before an edit can be approved and possibly a character limit of some sort...if the post needs more than 50 characters to edit it might not be a suitable candidate.

Comment: @michael_timofeev 50 characters that's a lot, sometimes a typo and a little reformatting take up about, what, 10 characters? The edit didn't pass through, the system "worked", if it had passed through, somebody would have noticed it. Users who review edits need to be trained, that's what needs to be done! :) This is all voluntary work, nobody gets paid to ask, answer, review, edit or tidy up. You can only warn the user not to repeat that malicious edit. If he/she does, then they get suspended.

Comment: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6838/44619 and http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/why-does-an-edit-have-to-be-at-least-6-characters

Comment: I don't get what your complaint is. The edit did not go through. And if it did, someone (you?) could have edited back. If an edit war happens, at that point a meta post might be called for. (I agree that the large text addition edits were not appropriate.) From the edit page it looked like 2 people had to approve/reject, so I think everything you want is already there.

Comment: @Mitch I don't really have a complaint about the system - although the ducking stool would seem appropriate to me. But the *intent* of the editor here was to deliberately overwrite someone else's answer because they disagreed with it. The fact that they displayed total ignorance about elementary grammar is not what worries me, I think what I wanted most was to verify that this kind of behaviour is completely out of order. If it happened several times, I wanted to know what would happen. I got good answers in the comments, and so I am happy. I agree that the review system worked well here.

Comment: Your insistence on 'ducking stool' implies that you felt terribly hurt by this seeming transgression. Chill out. The behavior is not 'out of order'; that is an extreme and tendentious description of the event. The manner of those changes is, I feel not recommended, and the response would be to inform the editor that it was too much, not to (yes, humorously) expect moral retribution. Lots of people's submissions get edited, don't take it so personally.

Comment: It sounds like you want there to be absolutely no editing except by the original author.

Comment: @Mitch Are you really trying to defend the vandalism of posts?

Comment: I've never defended vandalism.  You should migrate this to SO (because this is ELU-agnostic; it would affect the entire SO software). Also, activity of the kind you suggested doing yourself in your deleted comments (like frivolous edits) are bannable offenses.

Comment: @Mitch Are you being serious? I cut my comments down because there was just way too much here. For the record, I said  "can I do the same kind of thing to your posts?" Exactly what is "bannable" about that? And you *have* defended vandalism. The reason that you say that what I wrote is "bannable" is because I satirically asked you whether you would give me permission to frivolously edit your posts. Asking you to idiotically give me permission to do so, is just to point out that it would be idiotic of you to do so. It's not to be able to carry out the kind of idiotic vandalism that you support.

Comment: @Mitch Did you actually read the edit comment by the editor?

Comment: Argh. So many misunderstandings. Chat?

Comment: @Mitch Sure but maybe tomorrow? Small comment boxes and no intonation ----> misunderstandings.